# Java 8 equivalent of (RxJava) Observable#onComplete()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, rx-java

I'm getting to know [Java 8 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and I am unsure how to signal to a consumer of a stream that the stream is completed.

In my case the results of the stream-pipeline will be written in batches to a database or published on a messaging service. In such cases the stream-pipeline should invoke a method to "flush" and "close" the endpoints once the stream is closed.

I had a bit of exposure to the *Observable* pattern as implemented in [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki) and remember the `Observer#onComplete` method is used there for this purpose.

On the other hand Java 8 `Consumer` only exposes an `accept` method but no way to "close" it. Digging in the library I found a sub-interface of `Consumer` called `Sink` which offers an `end` method, but it's not public. Finally I thought of implementing a `Collector` which seems to be the most flexible consumer of a stream, but isn't there any simpler option?

Comment: Of course, there is. When the call to the terminal operation, e.g. `Stream.forAll(Consumer)` returns, the operation is complete. Just place the on complete action as an ordinary statement right after that.

Comment: I've published a project illustrating the case using a toy "Processor" application: https://github.com/spaceCamel/reactive-stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of doing a final operation is by placing the appropriate statement right after the terminal operation of the stream, for example:

```
IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println("done");
```

This operation will be performed in the successful case only, where a commit is appropriate. While the `Consumer`s run concurrently, in unspecified order, it is still guaranteed that all of them have done their work upon normal return.

Defining an operation that is also performed in the exceptional case is not that easy. Have a look at the following example:

```
try(IntStream is=IntStream.range(0, 100).onClose(()->System.out.println("done"))) {
    is.parallel().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This works like the first one but if you test it with an exceptional case, e.g.

```
try(IntStream is=IntStream.range(0, 100).onClose(()->System.out.println("done"))) {
    is.parallel().forEach(x -> {
        System.out.println(x);
        if(Math.random()>0.7) throw new RuntimeException();
    });
}
```

you might encounter printouts of numbers *after* `done`. This applies to all kind of cleanup in the exceptional case. When you catch the exception or process a `finally` block, there might be still running asynchronous operations. While it is no problem rolling back a transaction in the exceptional case at this point as the data is incomplete anyway, you have to be prepared for still running attempts to write items to the now-rolled-back resource.

Note that `Collector`-based solutions, which you thought about, can only define a completion action for the successful completion. So these are equivalent to the first example; just placing the completing statement after the terminal operation is the simpler alternative to the `Collector`.

---

If you want to define operations which implement both, the item processing and the clean up steps, you may create your own interface for it and encapsulate the necessary `Stream` setup into a helper method. Here is how it might look like:

Operation interface:

```
interface IoOperation<T> {
    void accept(T item) throws IOException;
    /** Called after successfull completion of <em>all</em> items */
    default void commit() throws IOException {}
    /**
     * Called on failure, for parallel streams it must set the consume()
     * method into a silent state or handle concurrent invocations in
     * some other way
     */
    default void rollback() throws IOException {}
}
```

Helper method implementation:

```
public static <T> void processAllAtems(Stream<T> s, IoOperation<? super T> c) 
throws IOException {
    Consumer<IoOperation> rollback=io(IoOperation::rollback);
    AtomicBoolean success=new AtomicBoolean();
    try(Stream<T> s0=s.onClose(() -> { if(!success.get()) rollback.accept(c); })) {
        s0.forEach(io(c));
        c.commit();
        success.set(true);
    }
    catch(UncheckedIOException ex) { throw ex.getCause(); }
}
private static <T> Consumer<T> io(IoOperation<T> c) {
    return item -> {
        try { c.accept(item); }
        catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    };
}
```

Using it without error handling might be as easy as

```
class PrintNumbers implements IoOperation<Integer> {
    public void accept(Integer i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    @Override
    public void commit() {
        System.out.println("done.");
    }
}
processAllAtems(IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().boxed(), new PrintNumbers());
```

Dealing with errors is possible, but as said, you have to handle the concurrency here. The following example does also just print number but use a new output stream that should be closed at the end, therefore the concurrent `accept` calls have to deal with concurrently closed streams in the exceptional case.

```
class WriteNumbers implements IoOperation<Integer> {
    private Writer target;
    WriteNumbers(Writer writer) {
        target=writer;
    }
    public void accept(Integer i) throws IOException {
        try {
            final Writer writer = target;
            if(writer!=null) writer.append(i+"\n");
            //if(Math.random()>0.9) throw new IOException("test trigger");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            if(target!=null) throw ex;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void commit() throws IOException {
        target.append("done.\n").close();
    }
    @Override
    public void rollback() throws IOException {
        System.err.print("rollback");
        Writer writer = target;
        target=null;
        writer.close();
    }
}
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
FileChannel fch = fos.getChannel();
Writer closableStdIO=new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
try {
    processAllAtems(IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().boxed(),
                    new WriteNumbers(closableStdIO));
} finally {
    if(fch.isOpen()) throw new AssertionError();
}
```

Comment: But the _final operation_ will be consumer-dependend. Putting it outside the consumer of the stream **seems to increase coupling and/or reduce cohesion**. Seeing this from a testing angle I wonder how can I mock the consumer in order to check that the _final operation_ is invoked?
The fact that it's not easy to deal with the exceptional case seems to confirm my point, as the stream object could know when every thread returned and invoke the _final operation_ only then.
Said this, you might be right: sticking to JDK-only that might be simpler then a collector.

Comment: You can wrap the `forEach` call and the follow-up statement into a helper method that receives an extended `Consumer` `interface` which has that final operation.

Comment: @Holdger I see only now your implementation. Sorry I did not include it in on the GitHub project (see my comment to the question). I'll try to do it later.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal operations on Java 8 streams (like `collect()`, `forEach()` etc) will always complete the stream.

If you have something that is processing objects from the Stream you know when the stream ends when the Collector returns.

If you just have to close your processor, you can wrap it in a try-with-resource and perform the terminal operatoni inside the try block

```
try(BatchWriter writer = new ....){

       MyStream.forEach( o-> writer.write(o));

 }//autoclose writer
```

Comment: Beware. The guaranty for the terminal operation is only for a normal return and its result, if any. If an exception occurs, it might get delivered while there is still code running in other threads, in other words, the `try` with resources might close a resource that is still being accessed by some `Consumer`s. Not that it matters for the `Writer` as in this case the data will be incomplete anyway but you should be prepared for an already closed stream within the `Consumer`s then, to avoid tons of followup-exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stream#onClose(Runnable) to specify a callback to invoke when the stream is closed. Streams are pull-based (contrary to push-based rx.Observable), so the hook is associated with stream, not it's consumers

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but works well.
Create a stream concatenation of the original + a unique object.

Using peek(), see if the new object is encountered, and call the onFinish action.

Return the stream with filter, so that the unique object won't be returned.

This preserves the onClose event of the original stream.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> onFinish(Stream<T> stream, Runnable action) {
    final Object end = new Object(); // unique object

    Stream<Object> withEnd = Stream.concat(stream.sequential(), Stream.of(end));
    Stream<Object> withEndAction = withEnd.peek(item -> {
        if (item == end) {
            action.run();
        }
    });
    Stream<Object> withoutEnd = withEndAction.filter(item -> item != end);
    return (Stream<T>) withoutEnd;
}
```

Another option is to wrap the original spliterator, and when it returns false, call the action.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> onFinishWithSpliterator(Stream<T> source, Runnable onFinishAction) {
    Spliterator<T> spliterator = source.spliterator();

    Spliterator<T> result = new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(source.estimateSize(), source.characteristics()) {
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            boolean didAdvance = source.tryAdvance(action);
            if (!didAdvance) {
                onFinishAction.run();
            }
            return didAdvance;
        }
    };

    // wrap the the new spliterator with a stream and keep the onClose event
    return StreamSupport.stream(result, false).onClose(source::close);

}
```